# Best solution for storing files securely in a office where multiple people use the same PCs all with admin windows accounts

Tags: windows, networking, onedrive-for-business

We're a small business with 5 employees. As such owners and employees share the same PCs. The owners might have documents which as sensitive in nature and the employees could be using the same PCs and need to be local admins (to install programs etc). The issue with the employees being local admins is that they can see all the files in the PC.

The files in question are stored on the PCs in OneDrive folders.

We've looked at making the employees only local non admin users in Windows but this is not practical.

We're currently considering ordering a NAS that the owners could dial into but we've found that when credentials were put in by an admin in the past all the on admin Windows 10 users on that physical PC automatically got access - so this isn't ideal either.

Answer (score 0):

To save on the same server sensitive documents ask for kind of encrypted storage like VeraCrypt. So only person who know the password can unlock and mount the volume.

About NAS you can choose to make every user to login in NAS with different account (create accounts in NAS itself).

Comment: A mounted VeraCrypt volume will be available to all logged in users.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, true if they login simultaneously.

Comment: I've used VeraCrypt before with Dropbox and it was not a happy pairing. Files were updated etc. I would probably avoid it as we need to use OneDrive too. But thanks for the opinions.